# Join lines of orders in the same array

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting all orders and lines of a user in mysql.

The problem is that I am getting each line in a sepparate object.

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#362 (7) {
    ["id_order"]=>int(2)
    ["payment_methods"]=>string(11) "Credit Card"
    ["total_price"]=>int(20)
    ["price"]=>int(10)
    ["date_order"]=>string(10) "2020-05-06"
    ["quantity"]=>int(1)
    ["name"]=>string(17) "Taza Tummys White"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#366 (7) {
    ["id_order"]=>int(3)
    ["payment_methods"]=>string(11) "Credit Card"
    ["total_price"]=>int(20)
    ["price"]=>int(25)
    ["date_order"]=>string(10) "2020-05-07"
    ["quantity"]=>int(1)
    ["name"]=>string(40) "Camiseta Manga Corta Unisex Tummys Black"
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#344 (7) {
    ["id_order"]=>int(2)
    ["payment_methods"]=>string(11) "Credit Card"
    ["total_price"]=>int(20)
    ["price"]=>int(10)
    ["date_order"]=>string(10) "2020-05-06"
    ["quantity"]=>int(1)
    ["name"]=>string(24) "Alfombrilla Tummys Black"
  }
}
```

As you can see I have 2 orders Id_order 2 and 3.

Is there anyway to get the lines of a order groupped and not in this way? Or getting the lines of a order groupped?

```
  $historiales = User::select('lines.id_order','orders.payment_methods','orders.total_price','products.price','orders.date_order','lines.quantity','products.name')
            ->join('orders','users.id','=','orders.id_user')
            ->join('lines','orders.id','=','lines.id_order')
            ->join('products','lines.id_product','=','products.id')
            ->where('orders.id',Auth::user()->id)
            ->get();
```

This is the sql statement I am using.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `->orderBy('id_order')` is that what you mean?

Comment: It can work, but I am doing a for each to $historiales and create a td for each order. How can I know if the next line is from the same order?

Comment: Thats a Simple case of remember the id you are processing, is the next one the same? If so them merge them or whatever